# SFDMU - Setting two lookups to same record - odd behavior

Tags: data-loader, salesforcedx-cli, sfdmu

I am using SFDMU to upsert an object that has two lookups to the same object - Zip__c.  I'm seeing really curious behavior.  I run the process once - and it only populates one of the two Zip lookups.  Then I run the process a second time (making no changes to anything in the sfdmu config, etc), and it populates the second Zip lookup.  I've tried this entire process three times and I get the exact same results each time.
I included a sample row of data below.  (Note that there are also two lookups to another object: RS - and I see the same errant behavior with those fields.)

```
Active__c,External_ID__c,Active_RS__r.External_ID__c,RS__r.External_ID__c,Active_Zip__r.External_ID__c,Zip__r.External_ID__c
"True","AUIZAKYAA","KYAA","KYAA","41071","41071"
```

After running the first time, the target file looks correct I think - all values are populated.  Pasted below.

```
Active__c,External_ID__c,Active_RS__c,RS__c,Active_Zip__c,Zip__c,Errors,Id
false,AUIZA-000001,a0G830000009QWdEAM,a0G830000009QWdEAM,a6U3S0000000KqlUAE,a6U3S0000000KqlUAE,,a5v3S0000000D2MQAU
```

Any idea what's happening here?  I've only been working with SFDMU a few days, so I could definitely have some bad config somewhere...

My export.json is below.

```
{
    "objectSets": [
    {
        "objects": [

            {
                "query": "SELECT Name,External_ID__c FROM Zip__c",
                "externalId": "External_ID__c",
                "operation": "Readonly"
            },
            {
                "query": "SELECT Name,External_ID__c FROM AIE_Unit_Hierarchy__c",
                "externalId": "External_ID__c",
                "operation": "Readonly"
            },
            {
                "query": "SELECT Active__c,External_ID__c,Active_Recruiting_Station_Hierarchy__c,Recruiting_Station__c,Active_Zip__c,Zip__c FROM Station_ID_to_Zip_Assignment__c",
                "operation": "Upsert",
                "externalId": "External_ID__c"        
            }
        ]

    }
    ],
    "excludeIdsFromCSVFiles": "true"
}
```

I appreciate your time.
chris

Comment: Can you please share your export.json file?

Comment: I added the export.json to the initial post.